Telegram bot in Python linking GitHub with Heroku
GitHubLink Does anyone know why an error in Heroku Dashboard appears when I deploy branch? The manual deploy by connecting to my Github repo branch works fine and says it deployed successfully, but when I visit the page I get the error message
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
enter image description here
I need help to solve this issue
Here the logs:
enter image description here
enter image description here

Can you provide the logs? We cannot help you if we don't know what's wrong.

Done, and included in the text. Thank you.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Your issue is in the Python code, not the deployment. Although the deployment was successful, the Python code throws an error when executed.
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence
To resolve this, you need to modify the file /app/bot-team.py at line 44:
Change this:
image_path = 'C:\Python\PythScripts\pepedjen.jpg'

To this:
image_path = 'C:/Python/PythScripts/pepedjen.jpg'
# OR
image_path = 'C:\\Python\\PythScripts\\pepedjen.jpg'

This warning occurs because backslashes () are used for escape sequences in Python strings. Using a forward slash (/) or double backslashes (\) will avoid this issue.
Make sure you do this for all path directories in your application.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
Additionally, you have a ModuleNotFoundError for the telebot module. Ensure you have installed the module by running:
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Make sure to install the module in the same Python environment.

Hello, thank you! now it appears the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with pip install pyTelegramBot. Do you know why could this happen-?

Are you installing the packages from a requirements.txt file?

yes, you can see the github project in the description. Again the same SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with pip install pyTelegramBot

In bot-team.py, you put the following line:
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI 
The pip install command needs to be run in the terminal, not in the Python file.

Sorry, in the terminal from GitHub, or what do you mean?

In the deployment terminal
The error is occurring because you placed the pip install pyTelegramBotAPI command in bot-team.py. This command should not be in the Python file.
Instead, it should be in the requirements.txt file (as it already is). Ensure that dependencies are being installed during your application's deployment, using a command like:
pip install -r requirements.txt
This way, all necessary packages listed in requirements.txt will be installed correctly during deployment.

Hello! pip install -r requirements.txt is giving a sintaxis error, do you know why this could have happened? The link to GitHub is above :)

Try this on install.py.
`import subprocess
Define the command to be executed
command = ['pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
Execute the command
subprocess.run(command, check=True)`

Hello again! This error appears now "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 120 seconds of launch" in the log

This is another error, can you open another question and close this?
